# Android: How to determine which keyboard is in use

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to do some simple, but, as it comes difficult task.
I have EditText control. What I want to do is when I stop typing in it(onFocusChanged, focus = false) I want to record the state of the keyboard - which language was in use and next time if I see that the keyboard was 'remembered' I want to set it as it was before.

I tried to look into IMF and IME but these only give me some info but without 'set' option, so this is not what I need. 
On the other hand there is KeyboardView - there are some functions that can help(getKeyboard, setKeyboard) but I don't know how to obtain KeyboardView!

Why do I need this? I have 2 EditText, the language in each of them will be different, so the user must change the language by himself, which is very irritating, as the number of input iterations is high. If only I could remember the used keyboard...:)

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
public InputMethodInfo getCurrentImeInfo(){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

    final int n = mInputMethodProperties.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        InputMethodInfo imeInfo = mInputMethodProperties.get(i);

        if (imeInfo.getId().equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {

            return imeInfo;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This does not help me with setting the right keyboard the next time..
And I don't really understand what does it have to do with DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD..

Comment: `InputMethodInfo` has id, which can be used in `InputMethodManager.setInputMethod`

Comment: This id gives me the name of the keyboard I use, but not the language I chose in this keyboard:)

Comment: Ok, it looks like it is not possible because of:
1)There is no such thing as 'Language' property in InputTypeMethod or Info or whatever.
2)If there was such a property, android security policy would not let me read it as it would be a kind of keyboard logging which is not possible.

The security policy can be found here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#SHOW_IMPLICIT

Comment: Thanks so much - a method that identifies the keyboard!! So many people said it couldn't be done.